# Prove the solution of a differential equation is a constant map

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f: I \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a $C^1$ map and consider the differential equation

$$x''(t)=-f'(x(t))$$

Prove that if $x:[a,b] \rightarrow I$ is a solution to the above equation, then

$$t \rightarrow \frac{(x'(t))^2}{2}+f(x(t))$$ is a constant map.

So this is the first time i see a question like that and don't really know how to approach it. I watched a few videos on how to check solutions but didn't help much.

And other than that i have a question on notation:

Does $-f'(x(t))$ mean the same as $-x'(t)$?

And how would you know if the solution $t$ is a constant map?

Comment: Consider the function $g(t) = \frac{(x'(t))^2}{2}+f(x(t))$ and compute $g'(t)$ ...

Comment: $-f'(x(t))$ is $(-1) \cdot f'(x(t))$, why should that be the same as $-x'(t)$?

Comment: @Martin R sorry i watched a video on youtube where the guy said its just different notation but means the same. Ill try using your first comment to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us set
$$H(x, \dot x) = \frac{\dot x^2}{2} + f(x).$$
Therefore, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}H(x(t), \dot x(t)) &= \dot x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} H(x, \dot x) + \ddot x \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot x} H(x, \dot x)\\
&= \dot x f'(x) + \dot x\ddot x\\
&= \dot x(f'(x) + \ddot x) = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: I'm sorry could you elaborate on how you took the derivative...I don't follow the steps

Comment: which equality?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}H(x(t),x'(t))=x'\frac{\partial}{\partial x}H(x,x') +x''\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}H(x,x')$ This one. Is this the chain rule?

Comment: Yes it is exactly the chain rule. You can find the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case).

Comment: Ah thank you, i havnt been yet introduced to multivariate chain rule so i didnt quite follow it the first time....Thank you!!!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: sorry to call you up on this again....I can't solve the second part of the problem: Given $x''(t)=-(x(t))^{-3},x(0)=1,x'(0)=0$, show that for sufficient small $t>0$,  $x'(t)=\frac{\sqrt{(1-x(t)^2)}}{x(t)}$ ...I tried plugging in the numbers, it didnt work...How would you do that? (Initial value problem, i wachted many videos on it too)